# Month difference for same date but different month

Tags: jquery

Choose `16-Jun-2019` and `16-May-2019` to calculate month difference; the answer is `0`, but it should be `1`.

If the first date is 16-May-19 and the other date from 16-June-19 up to (but not including) 16-July-19, then the result should be 1.

```js
$("#lastAssimilationDate").datepicker({
  yearRange: "-20:+100",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: "d-M-y"
});

$("#lastAssimilationDateOver").datepicker({
  yearRange: "-20:+100",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: "d-M-y"
});

function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
  var months;
  months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
  months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
  months += d2.getMonth();
  return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}

$('button').click(function() {
  d1 = new Date($("#lastAssimilationDate").val());
  d2 = new Date($("#lastAssimilationDateOver").val());
  alert(monthDiff(d1, d2));
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<input type='text' id="lastAssimilationDate" />
<input type='text' id="lastAssimilationDateOver" />
<button>press</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/mB6B7/1/

Comment: @freefaller it's a function the OP only included in the fiddle. I've edited the question to include all question so that the problem is clearer.

Comment: Please include all relevant code within the question itself. Only including half of it just leads to confusion, as the above comments show

Comment: So the difference between 30-May-2019 and 29-June-2019 is 0 months?
What about the difference between 31-May-2019 (last day of May) and 30-June-2019 (last day of June)? Would that still be 0 months?

Comment: Gunjan, if you are satisfied, please check the answer as 'accepted'. Otherwise, please tell us what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the absolute difference in months.

First of all, don't add 1 to the month, i.e. replace `months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;` by `months -= d1.getMonth();`

In the example, d1.getMonth() will be 5 and d2.getMonth() will be 4.
The difference is -1.

If you want the absolute difference, replace `return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;` by `return months <= 0 ? -months : months;`

In the example, the result will be 1.

The result so far:

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth();
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? -months : months;
}
```

But this does not take the day number into account.
If you want to take day numbers into account, you can use `getDate()`. The only case that the abovementioned function gives an incorrect result, is when the day component of the earlier date is greater than the day component of the later date. In that case, we need to subtract 1 from months.

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    if (d1 > d2) {
        months = monthDiff(d2,d1);
    } else {
        months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
        months += d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth();
        if (d1.getDate() > d2.getDate()) {
            months--;
        }
    }
    return months;
}
```

Comment: Lets consider these test cases where above code doesn't gives desired results

15-May-19 and 01-July-19 result is coming 2 but my desired result is 1. If you select any first date as 15-May-19 and the other date between 15-July-19 to 15-Aug-19  result should be 2 for this case only but it's giving me 2 after 1-July-19.

Comment: Please check if the following is true:

   (--1--)   If first date is 15-May-19, then any other date between 15-June-19 and 15-July-19 should give 1 as result?

   (--2--)   If first date is 15-May-19, then any other date between 15-May-19 and 15-June-19 should give 0 as result?

If these are both correct, why do you say, in your question, that 16-June and 17-May should not give difference zero?

Comment: Why 15-May-19 to 1-Jul-19 is giving me 2 instead of 1 ?

Comment: Because monthDiff only compares year numbers and month numbers, not day numbers. If you want to compare day numbers, you can use getDate().

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check after removing + 1 from the d1.getMonth() + 1 problem with same is gone I am getting 1 for difference of 16 May to 16 June but for 16 May to 1 Jul I am getting 2 but I should get 1.

Comment: So what should be the code for it to get the required result.

Comment: I have changed my answer. I have also changed your question, so that it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have check on your code. It seems there is bug there.
Let see this code:

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
   var months;
   months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
   months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
   months += d2.getMonth();
   return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
```

}

The bug is happen when you substract months with d1.getMonth + 1.

```
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
```

You can change your code to be like this:

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
   var months;
   months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
   months = months - d1.getMonth() + d2.getMonth();
   return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
```

}

Then try to input 17-May-2019 as lastAssimilationDate input and
16-Jun-2019 as lastAssimilationDateOver.